# Trying to print a list after user says "Done" or "None"

Tags: python, list, if-statement, break

I am trying to create a simple input query that will print the list of a users favorite planes after they say "Done" or will print "User does not have a favorite plane" if they input "None."

Here is the code I used to try and make the it print or break the list depending on what the user input. I also attached a screenshot so you can see it all.

[Screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQDLg.png)

```py
Planes = [] #Start with empty list

while True:
    Plane = input ('What are your favorite planes?\n ') #input asking user favorite planes
    if Plane == ('None', 'I have none', "What's a plane?"):
        print ("User has no favorite planes.")
        break
    elif Planes.append(Plane): #Adding plane to list
        print(Planes)
    else:
        Plane == ("Done")
        print (Planes)
```

Comment: So, did you encounter any problems?

Comment: What if the user says "Whats a plane" or "don't have any"? I reccomend appending `[n]one for none` to the input function and using `if Plane[0].lower() == "n"` instead, which tells the user what to write and matches the letter n being the first letter.
Same for "Done", which could be matched with `if Plane[0].lower() == "d"`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want to ask about, but the input `Plane` from the user is a string and will never be equal to the tuple `('None', 'I have none', "What's a plane?")`. Also, `Planes.append(Plane)` returns `None` so that the `elif` branch will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just replaced two lines.

```
Plane == ("Done")
```

should probably be in the elif, and you can't compare a string to a tuple, so you need to change that too.

```
Planes = [] #Start with empty list
while True:
    Plane = input ('What are your favorite planes?\n ') #input asking user favorite planes
    if Plane in ('None', 'I have none', "What's a plane?"):
        print ("User has no favorite planes.")
        break
    elif Plane == ("Done"): #Adding plane to list
        print(Planes)
    else:
        Planes.append(Plane)
```

notice it won't stop running when the user enter "None" or "Done", if you want the program to end, you should change the while condition